# How to attach image in mail from iPhone gallery?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I can retrieve image from iPhone gallery and showed it in imageView but i cant attach it in the mail...it just shows a ? image in the mail.... Can any one help me out of this...
thanx in advance

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/screenshot20120525at124.png/

here is the screen shot of wat i get while sending mail....

Comment: Please look at my updated answer, it could be just because of the delay

Comment: The problem am facing is image is not attached in mail instead empty image with question mark is attached...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to have something like this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[picker setSubject:....]
...
```

All you have to do is:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"TheNameYouWant"];
```

Where `image` is of type `UIImage`.

UPDATE:

Couldn't it be just a matter of a delay? The screenshot you posted is exactly the image I get when it's just loading the image. Have you tried to wait some seconds...?

Comment: ok i did already wat u have said....how to get Image name which i choose it from gallery...

Comment: What was right? My first answer or the updated one? (just to update my post)

Answer (score 2):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
[picker setSubject:@"My Image Is Attached"];

// other mail settings here

//Attachment imageData1 is NSData of your image.
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData1 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"foo.png"]
```

Comment: ok i did already wat u have said....how to get Image name which i choose it from gallery...

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello"];


// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: ok i did already wat u have said....how to get Image name which i choose it from gallery...

Answer (score 1):

First of all import framework named - MessageUI.framework in your project.

Then import

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

in your viewcontroller.h part. Now add the delegate

```
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Now you are able to use Mail composer view.

```
-(IBAction)showMail:(id)sender //this is your UIButton action
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
    [picker setSubject:@"write your subject here"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]; 

    //convert UIImage to NSData to add it as attachment

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    //this is how to attach any data in mail, remember mimeType will be different
    //for other data type attachment.

   [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"image.png"];

   //showing MFMailComposerView here
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

You can dismiss MFMailComposerView after finished your work, like this:-

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(result == MFMailComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Mail has cancelled");
    if(result == MFMailComposeResultSaved)
        NSLog(@"Mail has saved");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Thank You!

Comment: you dont need to get name of image which you are picking from phone library, you can convert UIImage to NSData directly- like this NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); image is UIImage whatever it is. then attach this nsdata to your mail.